# what is the replacement of long nested if else construct?

Tags: language-agnostic

I have a nested if else construct like below and i wanted to replace this 
with the right type of programming statement.

```
if($provider[0][0]=='A' && $provider[1][0]=='B'){
   return 'O';
}elseif($provider[0][0]=='B' && $provider[1][0]=='A'){
   return 'O';
}elseif($provider[0][0] == 'A' && $provider[1][0] == '' ){
   return 'A';
}elseif($provider[0][0] == 'B' && $provider[1][0] == '' ){
   return 'B';
} else{
   return 'Return nothing';
}
```

Comment: Please format the code.

Comment: I tagged this language-agnostic because apparently the language isn't important.

Comment: In this case you can avoid the nesting, as the return will break the flow. Anyway, I guess this is not the answer you needed...

Comment: Depending on language (like C and derived languages) an expression like `provider[1][0] == ''` will not work.

Comment: Some context as to why you want to change from if/else would help in getting you a better solution.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I don't think so. E.g. in many functional languages we can use pattern matching which will slightly simplify such code.

Comment: @om-nom-nom the question was tagged C++, C, Java and PHP - clearly the op doesn't care what he gets his answer in.

Comment: This code really looks odd and definitely the complexity increases as the conditions increase, so wanted to have a correct code with the same functionality.

Comment: Clearly the possible solutions will vary among languages, but in any language with the basic concept of functions or methods, there will be at least some similar options for improving this. I would think the question is clear and legitimate, and appropriately tagged as language-agnostic.

Comment: In Scheme (and most Lisps), it is `cond`

Comment: If language does not matter, then pattern matching is the best option.

Answer (score 2):

Not really avoiding nesting, but simplifying the reading:

```
<?php

function isOprovider($provider) {
    return $provider[0][0]=='A' && $provider[1][0]=='B' 
           || $provider[0][0]=='B' && $provider[1][0]=='A';
}

function isAprovider($provider) {
    return $provider[0][0] == 'A' && $provider[1][0] == '';
}

function isBprovider($provider) {
    return $provider[0][0] == 'B' && $provider[1][0] == '';
}

if (isOprovider($provider)) {
     return '0';
} else if (isAprovider($provider)) {
     return 'A';
} else if (isBprovider($provider)) {
     return 'B';
} else {
     return 'Return nothing';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the options to make it more readable-

```
if($provider[0][0]=='A') {
   // other condition(s)
} else if($provider[0][0]=='B') {
   // other condition(s) 
} else {
  // return nothing
}
```

You may try switch as well. In any case you would need nested conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
function IsCombinationOf($first, $second, $provider) {
    return ($provider[0][0]==$first && $provider[1][0]==$second) || 
           ($provider[0][0]==$second && $provider[1][0]==$first);
}


if(IsCombinationOf('A', 'B', $provider)){
    return 'O';
}
elseif(IsCombinationOf('', '', $provider)){
    return 'Return Nothing';
}
elseif(IsCombinationOf('A', '', $provider)){
    return 'A';
}
elseif(IsCombinationOf('B', '', $provider)){
    return 'B';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would replace most of this code with data and then use a loop to select the correct answer from the data.  The idea here is to separate policy and implementation.  The policy is: Given different combinations of providers, what do I return?  The implementation is.... well, the implementation.

The example is in Ruby, but the idea applies to any language.

The data representing the policy might look like this:

```
PROVIDER_COMBOS = [
  ['A', 'B', 'O'],
  ['B', 'A', 'O'],
  ['A', '', 'A'],
  ['B', '', 'B'],
]
```

and the code that uses it might look like this:

```
def lookup_provider_combo(provider1, provider2)
  PROVIDER_COMBOS.each do |key1, key2, result|
    if provider1[0] == key1 && provider2[0] == key2
      return result
    end
  end
  return 'Return nothing'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking that if..else statement is not nested. It is flat. Also, it is technically already at the state of minimum complexity. It is fairly simple code. It does "look" messy though. And the thing that makes it look messy is it's verbosity (don't confuse verbosity/messiness for complexity).

But you are right in complaining about verbosity. Verbose code, especially one with a lot of repeated bits, harms readibility. For the code in the example, one of the first obvious thing you can do to make it more readable is to factor out the array syntax:

```
p1 = $provider[0][0];
p2 = $provider[1][0];

if (p1 == 'A' && p2 == 'B') {
   return 'O';
} elseif (p1 == 'B' && p2 == 'A') {
   return 'O';
} elseif (p1 == 'A' && p2 == '' ) {
   return 'A';
} elseif (p1 == 'B' && p2 == '' ) {
   return 'B';
} else {
   return 'Return nothing';
}
```

This alone removes cruft from the code making the logic clearer. There are other things you can do to remove more repeated bits from the code above to make it even clearer but they all boil down to what the code above does: basically a table of conditions and results.

In languages where the `switch` statement accept strings as input you can simply concatenate the two conditions into a single string as the switch condition:

```
switch (join([p1,p2],',')) {
    'A,B'   : return 'O'; break;
    'B,A'   : return 'O'; break;
    'A,'    : return 'A'; break;
    'B,'    : return 'B'; break;
    default : return 'Return nothing'; break;
}
```

This makes it even more obvious that what you're doing is consulting a table. Alternatively you can achieve a similar layout using the ternary operator:

```
cond = join([p1,p2],',');

return cond == 'A,B' ? 'O' :
       cond == 'B,A' ? 'O' :
       cond == 'A,'  ? 'A' :
       cond == 'B,'  ? 'B' :
       'Return nothing';
```

Admittedly that still has the `cond ==` bit repeated. But it is slightly easier to see the table compared to the original if..else statement.

In languages that has a dictionary/associative array/hash, you can simply encode the logic in a data structure and simply read that data structure:

```
conditions = {
    'A' : {
        'B' : 'O',
        ''  : 'A'
    },
    'B' : {
        'A' : 'O',
        ''  : 'B'
    }
}

result = conditions[p1][p2];

return result ? result : 'Return nothing';
```

Alternatively you can also use the following data structure:

```
conditions = {
    'A,B' : 'O',
    'B,A' : 'O',
    'A,'  : 'A',
    'B,'  : 'B'
}

result = conditions[join([p1,p2],',')];

return result ? result : 'Return nothing';
```

Keeping the conditional logic as pure data instead of code makes it even more obvious that what we're doing is looking up a table. Another advantage of keeping the conditions as pure data is that you can potentially create the data structure at runtime by reading it from a file (or from a socket over the internet). For example, the logic can potentially be encoded in a JSON or YAML formatted file and you can make the logic programmable.

As you can see, there are many ways to do this but it depends on what features are available in your programming language. They are all of the same complexity (and most compile to the same thing). The only difference is in terms of readability and maintainability.